# Did I busted my Pi 4? Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)

Tags: bootloader

I powered down my Pi 4 with the shutdown operation, waiting until the screen turned black, then waiting for the LEDs to stop blinking with only one red solid led, then unplugged the power source.
I powered it back on and it started failing with `Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)`

I tried re-flashing a new microSD; I tried to flash a Bootloader "SD card boot" with the Raspberry Pi Imager and even this card result in the same result.

Please help! Did my 100$CAD Raspberry Pi 4 just got busted, can it be so fragile??

[image: cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001]

Comment: Have you read the Pi4 boot sticky https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: looking at the top of image, the card is detected, but it seems to read all zeros from the MBR ... do you have a usb thumb drive? you could try flashing raspberry pi os on that and see if it boots from USB ... if it does, then perhaps there's a physical issue with the sd slot

Comment: @CoderMike I had not read it thanks. The red and green led stay on without flashing when booting without an SD card, so I assume the bootloader is not working correctly. I will attempt to follow the instruction to recover it.

Comment: @CoderMike the instruction to repair the bootloader with recovery.bin is not clear. I mean whatever I put on my sdcard doesnt seem to have any effect. That specific SD card was working before. I have identical ones that also fail to work.

Comment: @Bravo booting from USB works. How can I confirm I screwed up my hardware? Is there a warranty? I've booted this Raspberry Pi 4 less than 10 times...

Comment: `Is there a warranty?` not for damage you may have caused - you yourself say it worked before you power cycled - assuming you haven't left out anything between removing the power and re-connecting the power it's quite odd that the sd card reader failed. When you boot using USB, can you plug in the SD card and read it? Perhaps, somehow, your eeprom was flashed to not boot from SD card before you powered down - though that too is unlikely as clearly there is an error condition trying to read the sdcard

Comment: The USB boot now doesnt work anymore.. the Pi is completely unusable now. It booted once from USB and now doesnt boot again anymore. I think there is some serious hardware failure on this board... it is out of warranty now, I bought it in 2020.

Comment: I have exactly the same Raspberry Pi with the same firmware and the exact same problem. Did you solve it finally?