# Raspberry Pi 400 Boot Failure: "failed to open device 'SDCARD'"

Tags: sd-card, boot-issues, pi-400

Encountered Error:

The Raspberry Pi 400 displays the following error message upon boot:

`failed to open device 'SDCARD' cmd 371a010 status 1fff00001`

Background:

1. I used the official Raspberry Pi Imager to flash a 64-bit Ubuntu Server image onto a 64GB Samsung EVO SD card.
2. The Raspberry Pi 400 has been unused for several months.
3. Similar issues reported online:

- https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=277580
- https://forum.argon40.com/t/failed-to-open-device-sdcard-cmd-371a0010-status-1fff0001/679
- [Did I busted my Pi 4? Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135963/did-i-busted-my-pi-4-failed-to-open-device-sdcard-cmd-371a0010-status-1fff0)

Additional Information:

Attempting to boot from a USB drive containing the same Ubuntu Server image resulted in a successful boot, but SSH connections are failing, and various messages appear on the monitor screen.

Request for Assistance:

I kindly request your assistance in troubleshooting and resolving this boot failure issue on my Raspberry Pi 400. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different SD card for your Raspberry Pi.  Inspect the SD card for any physical damage or signs of wear and tear. A damaged SD card may not function properly. You can also check this thread regarding the same error message: [Did I busted my Pi 4? Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135963/did-i-busted-my-pi-4-failed-to-open-device-sdcard-cmd-371a0010-status-1fff0)